# On hover of an image change to another image?

Tags: css, image, animation, hover

Basically what I'm looking for is to be able to make an image do a rotation of 360 degrees and enlarge the image, I already have these two down.

What I need to do now is, work out how to actually make it rotate 360 degrees and enlarge to a different image, here's the css that I have:

```
.rotate img {
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.rotate img:hover {
    cursor: crosshair
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
}
```

This code works fine, all I need to know is how to make it turn into a different image.

Comment: Not possible with CSS, could be done with Javascript though by swapping out the image source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a `<div>` with a background image rather than an actual `<img>` you can do it with css pretty easily.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/kJLGw/1/)**

```
.rotate {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-7.jpg") no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
    width:100px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.rotate:hover {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-8.jpg") no-repeat;
    cursor: crosshair;
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.25);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. All works perfectly. Thanks for that code.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with some JavaScript added in...  Also - rotate 2 divs rather than the img.  Place one image in each div, over the other.  As you rotate, fade the overlapping div (change the opacity) to 100%.  This will give you the effect of fading one image into the next.